# How do I stop my server side function from processing?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, event-handling

I have an asp:button that calls a client side function. The client side function gives a confirmation asking if the user wants to proceed. I have returned false however it is still proceeding with the server side function. Why is my client side function not stopping the process?

Here is my button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send To Feed Mill" Height="36px"
                                OnClick="btnSend_Click" OnClientClick="sendFeed_Click()" Visible="False" />
```

Here is my Javascript function:

```
    function sendFeed_Click() {
    $('.tonnage').each(function () {
        var maxTons = $(this).data("maxtons");
        if (this.value > maxTons) {
            if (confirm("The order amount is more than the maximum. Are you sure you wish to continue?")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Look up `preventDefault`

Comment: Okay will do. Thank you

Comment: Just tried it. Works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Zack.

Instead of returning true or false I implemented preventDefault() to stop the server side function from being called.